# How to tell when a VASP calculation has truly converged?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp

I am relatively new to VASP, and have been running a calculation with EDIFF = 1E-6, EDIFFG = -2E-2 (along with other INCAR settings). Some of the output is displayed below:

```
RMM:  60    -0.135836456109E+04   -0.15343E-03   -0.19255E-06  6759   0.687E-04    0.307E-03
RMM:  61    -0.135836464271E+04   -0.81625E-04   -0.10130E-06  6365   0.567E-04    0.209E-03
RMM:  62    -0.135836467403E+04   -0.31324E-04   -0.45355E-07  5815   0.432E-04    0.117E-03
RMM:  63    -0.135836469735E+04   -0.23318E-04   -0.42250E-07  5905   0.431E-04    0.996E-04
RMM:  64    -0.135836470743E+04   -0.10073E-04   -0.25642E-07  4379   0.344E-04    0.611E-04
RMM:  65    -0.135836471869E+04   -0.11263E-04   -0.24250E-07  4995   0.347E-04    0.533E-04
RMM:  66    -0.135836472806E+04   -0.93740E-05   -0.19322E-07  4646   0.324E-04    0.411E-04
RMM:  67    -0.135836473515E+04   -0.70842E-05   -0.12732E-07  4099   0.283E-04    0.551E-04
RMM:  68    -0.135836474052E+04   -0.53744E-05   -0.11116E-07  4087   0.276E-04    0.192E-04
RMM:  69    -0.135836474277E+04   -0.22460E-05   -0.40006E-08  2844   0.224E-04    0.937E-05
RMM:  70    -0.135836474462E+04   -0.18564E-05   -0.42948E-08  3112   0.241E-04    0.547E-05
RMM:  71    -0.135836474521E+04   -0.58510E-06   -0.13002E-08  2612   0.221E-04
   1 F= -.13883068E+04 E0= -.13882554E+04  d E =-.138831E+04
 BRION: g(F)=  0.255E+01 g(S)=  0.000E+00
 bond charge predicted
       N       E                     dE             d eps       ncg     rms          rms(c)
DAV:   1    -0.135669227260E+04    0.16725E+01   -0.26057E+02 13032   0.125E+01    0.473E+00
RMM:   2    -0.135723141009E+04   -0.53914E+00   -0.73892E+00 11853   0.187E+00    0.265E+00
RMM:   3    -0.135717390645E+04    0.57504E-01   -0.32633E-01 13321   0.391E-01    0.187E+00
RMM:   4    -0.135715075602E+04    0.23150E-01   -0.14709E-01 11877   0.241E-01    0.389E-01
RMM:   5    -0.135715910870E+04   -0.83527E-02   -0.87242E-03 12247   0.664E-02    0.108E+00
RMM:   6    -0.135715149509E+04    0.76136E-02   -0.23175E-03 12892   0.255E-02    0.316E-01
```

It seems like for N=71, |dE| < |EDIFF|, and it indeed does seem to interrupt the output with giving the total free energy. However, after this the calculation starts again at N=1 and just keeps going before eventually timing out. Why is this? Should the calculation not have stopped after it was converged? I have NSW = 100 in this calculation as well. Could it be that VASP is simply trying to reach 100 steps before the time limit is reached?

Thanks

Comment: +1 Welcome to our forum!

Comment: You seem to be confusing electronic minimization steps (see NELM, EDIFF) and ionic steps (see NSW, EDIFFG). Did you set IBRION in the INCAR? If not, it will default to doing molecular dynamics since you set NSW=100, so what you see is as expected - VASP does an electronic SCF, moves the atoms based on the forces and repeats. You could post your INCAR contents so we may better advise you.

Comment: Hello; I am using IBRION=1 (Quasi-Newton). I believe I now know what is going on. After some additional reading around, it seems that the electronic minimization is the first round of calculations, and once this converges then the ionic positions are updated before a new round of electronic minimization begins; is this correct? Thanks again.

Comment: Yup, that's right.  If you want a static calculation, set NSW to 0 (and IBRION to -1) and control the maximum number of SCF steps with NELM.

Comment: Please share your INCAR it seems that there are mistakes. Which functional are you using? What’s your compound? 
Good luck

Comment: @frobenius Hi friend. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Tom Hello, I believe that my issue was solved and that I was simply confusing electronic minimization and ionic steps. Thank you for the help!